# It is possible to run recent version of ScalaPB (0.6.x) with protobuf 2.5.0?

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, scalapb

did anyone try it? I need to generate scala classes for protobuf 2.5.0
Seems like ScalaPB supports protobuf 3.x and not 2.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... Nadav Samet answered to me in google group. it's impossible.
Quoting his answer:

> The problem is that the different versions of protobuf-java are not
>   binary compatible. So if it would work with 2.5.0 it wouldn't work
>   with 3.4.0. If the reason you need protobuf 2.5.x support is because
>   there's some other library that is stuck on that version, consider
>   asking them to move forward, or use a shaded version of protobuf-java
>   so the versions won't conflict.